# Is "seeked" event does not work in HTML audio element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html5-audio

My situation:

I have an audio element, and connect via websocket. When I pause, play, etc, the audio element of other people in my room does the same.

The problem is :

With `seeking` event, if someone plays with the seeking bar, I send thousands of websockets. So the `seeked` event was perfect, except that it does the same thing as the seeking event.

My question is simple. Does the `seeked` event on audio html element is working?

Because even on w3cSchool, that event seems to does not work.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_seeked2

```
sharedAudio[0].onseeked = function() {
        session.signal({
            type: 'seeking',
            data: sharedAudio[0].currentTime
        }, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error sending signal:', error.name, error.message);
            }
        });
    };
```

Did I do something wrong ?

If the event does not work properly, do you have a solution to simulate the same effect?

Comment: `onseeked` event worked for me at W3 Schools site. Why did you say it didnt work for you? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome V59. For me, the alert box pops instantly when I move in the seeking bar. For me the event 'seeked' is triggered when I have finished to seek like in the example of the video: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_seeked_seeking. Did I misunderstand the event ?

Comment: You can click on time-bar in order to move to a new position. Some how drag and drop is not working. Is that what you want to mention?

Comment: Try to change, in the first example the 'alert' by a 'console.log' and you will understand my problem.

Comment: I changes alert to `alert("Seek operation completed!" + this.currentTime);` and it worked perfectly for with offset of time in message.

Comment: The purpose of console.log is to not stop your js. Try console.log, play with the drag and drop and see the dozens of log you have.

Comment: Ohh. Now I understood what you meant.  You need to ignore the seeked event if current position is very near to previous position. Let me give you an example.

Comment: Yeah but I thought that was the purpose of 'seeked' event as opposite of 'seeking' which is triggered when you are changing the time. In the video example, the seeked event is doing exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

One can use below script to ignore `seeked` positions very near to each others.

```
<script>
var previousseekpos = 0;
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.addEventListener("seeked", function() {
    var currentSeekPos = this.currentTime;
    if( (currentSeekPos - previousseekpos) > 2.0)
    {
       alert("Seek operation completed!");
       previousseekpos = currentSeekPos;
    }
});
</script>
```

The `onseeked` event doest not elegantly handle drag and drop of caret position in scroll bar for audio control.

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I need. This is not a solution, because if I move for just 1 second, the event will not be triggered and will broke my app.

Comment: I know thats not perfect solution. That's why I have added note about behavior of drag/drop. You can tweak limit of time and use smaller value like 0.5 seconds. Also you have to consider taking absolute value as one can move caret left/right. I have left those for you to implement.

Comment: The problem is the same as the beginnig with a smaller value. If someone drag from 1:00 to 2:00, my app would send 60/.05=120 requests and I don't want that. I was just wondering is the video.seeked event is the same as the audio.seeked and it seems not. The audio.seeked and the audio.seeking events do the same thing.